# Will PLSR work on nonlinear dataset?

Tags: regression, partial-least-squares

Im new to this topic and a bit confused. When I read about PLSR on the web I only see examples where the original plot shows a somewhat linear relationship in the data set, but in my case I have a highly nonlinear relationship between input and output. Will PLSR work in these nonlinear cases? lets say for example a sine wave of data points. Will PLSR be able to make a prediction model of it?